# Connecting to SQL Server from another PC Using IP Address

Tags: sql-server, vb.net-2010

Searched Stackoverflow, and Google the past week, but I can't resolve my problem. I got to the point when I have to ask a question here. I hope I just lost in the overcomplicated forest really.

I have built an application in vb.net using sql server. Everything works like a dream. I use SQL server on the machine I develop my application. The application will need to access the data from the server from other machines, e.g. in the workplace from several machines, plus across the business... 
I have managed to pull data from the server using my laptop (different machine), hovever when I connect to a different newtwork then the application throwing and error message after try to log in. When the laptop is on the same network e.g. AndroidAP, TalkTalk... will let me to pull data remotely, but when the server machine connected on e.g. TalkTalk network, and the laptop connected to AndroidAP then error message comes up. 
My server machine updates the online DB table with the new IP address, and when the application (from other machine) try to connect will pull the IP address from the online table, and creating the connection string and try to connect.

Like I said, when both machines are connected to the same network, they can read and write data to the database, but when the connected networks are different then it will fail.

Could you please help me out in this matter?

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Comment: Without any relevant info it's impossible to help. There's no issue with using IP addresses to connect to SQL Server. Please provide the relevant information. What is your connection string, is the TCP protocol enabled, are SQL Server's ports open in Windows Firewall? There are countless questions in SO and articles on troubleshooting connectivity issues

Comment: Yes, TCP protocol is enabled, and the port is open as well. I even tried to turn firewall off. Comes to my mind that there is something different when connected to 2 different network, because when the network the same it communicates, otherwise not.

Comment: Nobody knows answer?